# Is it suggestable to import a project which is downloaded from git repository (as ZIP file)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, git, maven

I have one doubt, is it a good programming practice that I import a project which is in git repository (not by cloning the **URL** but by downloading as **ZIP**).
Screen Shot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8rlh.png)

Because many times I am faceing problems to RUN the downloaded project. After googling this I found this happens due to corrupted dependency jars and many time it is very difficult to remove the ERRORs to compile and Run, below screen shows that by importing a git repository (as ZIP) into Eclipse many dependency/jars get corrupted in **.m2** folder (though internet speed is good in my company)

```
    saroj.sahoo@user-261 MINGW64 ~/.m2
    $ find  repository/ -name "*jar" | xargs -L 1 zip -T | grep error | grep invalid
    warning [repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-elasticsearch/3.0.0.M4/spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.0.M4.jar]:  188369 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
      (attempting to process anyway)
    file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  188369
      (attempting to re-compensate)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-access/1.1.2/logback-access-1.1.2.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.0/jackson-core-2.5.0.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.5.0/jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.5.0/jackson-datatype-joda-2.5.0.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/1.5.3/gwt-user-1.5.3.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.4/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/glassfish/web/javax.el/2.2.5/javax.el-2.2.5.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.10.Final/hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/3.6.10.Final/hibernate-ehcache-3.6.10.Final.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.3.8.Final/hibernate-ehcache-4.3.8.Final.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.10.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.8.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/jadira/usertype/usertype.core/3.2.0.GA/usertype.core-3.2.0.GA.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/jvnet/opendmk/jmxremote_optional/1.0_01-ea/jmxremote_optional-1.0_01-ea.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/mortbay/jetty/cometd-jetty/6.1.12rc1/cometd-jetty-6.1.12rc1.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.12rc1/jetty-6.1.12rc1.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-embedded/6.1.26/jetty-embedded-6.1.26.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-java5-threadpool/6.1.26/jetty-java5-threadpool-6.1.26.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.3-1100-jdbc4/postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc4.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.10/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar)
    zip error: Zip file invalid, could not spawn unzip, or wrong unzip (original files unmodified)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.7.1.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-stream/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-integration-stream-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-acl/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-acl-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-taglibs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-taglibs-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-jms/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-jms-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-oxm/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-oxm-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-test/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-test-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/webflow/spring-js/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-js-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar)
    zip error: Zip file structure invalid (repository/org/springframework/webflow/spring-js-resources/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-js-resources-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar)
and many more..............
```

So how to eliminate this issue as I'm not interested to **CLONE the URL from git**?

Comment: The point is if you are downloading that way you are always downloading the latest version (SNAPSHOT) which are often not working...and releases which are marked by tags and usually those artifacts are often on Maven Central or on other repositories available...And If you have problems with `corrupted` dependencies you should turn on checksum policy to fail and furthermore use a repository manager...

Comment: But @khmarbaise i'm facing this problems by importing a repository which is not in active state(it's last commit was about  3 years ago).Here is the url:(https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example)